# windows local system account whoami shows a different result than %username%

Tags: windows, user-accounts, username

I'm learning about the "local system" account (aka "system" or SID "S-1-5-18") in Windows.  [This server fault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/168767/508066) is very helpful, but one thing I still don't understand is why the value returned by the `whoami` command is different from the `%username%` environment variable.

[image]

The latter is the name of my computer followed by a dollar sign "$".

Comment: Please edit the question with these answers : Which specific version of Windows is this (Windows 10v1809 for instance) ?  Are you starting cmd in a non-standard way, for instance, choosing "Run as Administrator" ?

Comment: Windows 7 Pro SP1, just start > run > cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Basically System is a special User, it effectively is your computers internal user so it kinda makes sense to use the hostname as name.

Take a look in Task Manager, go to the Details tabs and click PID ("Process ID") to sort the processes. The lowest few PIDs and the only process without a PID are all owned by SYSTEM and start at the earliest stages of the boot process. The Processes are run under the user "SYSTEM" and several are instances of ntoskrnl.exe - the Windows NT Kernel itself.

This [Windows startup process article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_startup_process) describes the general boot process and identifies the main components all of which are run as System.

Also worth mentioning the System user has special permissions so avoid modifying it or using it for none system tasks.

Comment: This doesn’t explain the reason *whoami* behaves the way it does.  It explains what the system user is, but that isn’t, what he author asked about